# Calculating similarity of a set of strings(tweets)

Tags: python, string, levenshtein-distance

I've an application that shows ~100 tweets of a trending topic. The thing is that a lot of them are really similar(i.e. same tweet with different url), that's why I'd like to ignore really similar tweets.

I'm trying to find an efficient way to do this with python. I'm thinking about using: http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/ to solve this, but I'll have to compare a lot of tweets with each other and maybe there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [difflib.get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) to compare each tweet with the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You really gotta try `difflib`, it has some cool stuff.  Here is one of my favorites:

```
>>>from difflib import SequenceMatcher as sm
>>> dif = sm(a='hello', b='maybe hello')
>>> dif.ratio()
0.625
>>> dif = sm(a='hello', b='Hello')
>>> dif.ratio()
0.8
>>> dif = sm(a=[1,2,3,4], b=[2,3,5,6])
>>> dif.ratio()
0.5
```